# Python code parser lib

Tags: python

I am searching for a Python lib to parse Python 3 code to some abstract representation. I don't need to modify code. I am fine with analyzation only. AST representation should be ok. What packages are potential candidates? What do you think about it (pros/cons)?

Requirements:

- abstraction of Python source code as AST (abstract syntax tree) or FST (full syntax tree)
- utilities to ease working with representation (pretty-printing, searching in representation, etc.)

Candidates:

- ast
- astroid
- baron
- parso
- etc.

Comment: What do you need that is not provided by the built-in `ast` module?

Comment: That's exactly this question is about. :) I am interested in things to look for when comparing parser libs.

Comment: I don't think that is on topic here.  This site is for asking about software that meets certain criteria, not asking what criteria you should ask about.

Comment: Ah ok. DId not know that. I adjust the question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is still not that great because you still didn't specify what your requirements are.  Again, the builtin `ast` module is the obvious choice.  If you don't want to use that you need to *explain* in your question what specific features you need.

Comment: It feel's like you want me to answer my question on my own :) E.g. `ast` has a plain AST, whereas `astroid` has an extended AST. `ast` has little helpers compared to other libs. I am interested in the experience of people which actually used more than just `ast`. Otherwise I wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: It's more that I think you need to answer a different question before you can ask one here.  :-)  To ask a question here, you need to already know what you want; but you instead seem to be asking what you should want.  You can't just ask a question like "I was thinking about some general software area, what do other people think about it?"  See [the on-topic definition](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You have provided neither a purpose nor any objective requirements.

Comment: I understand :) I'll try to improve the requirements list.